# I am unable to set CSS to selectic select box options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the electric select box after adding an option in the select box I am unable to set custom css to a particular option for ex.

```
<select class="form-control height_42px" id="slctSubPurpose" tabindex="0">
  <option value="">*Select Reason for Remittance</option>
  <option value="Rent1">Rent1</option>
  <option value="Rent2">Rent2</option>
  <option value="Security deposit for accommodation">Security deposit for accommodation</option>
  <option value="dfgdfg">dfgdfg</option>
  <option value="hg">hg</option>
</select>
```

After I add one option dynamically

```
$('#slctSubPurpose').append($('<option>', { 
  value: 'view more',
  text: 'View More'
}));    
$('#slctSubPurpose').selectric();
```

Now I want to change the style for 'View More' option only, but I can't. Please help me. I tried to add class but no effect is applied.

Comment: What style are you trying to apply to that `option` element? There's not a lot you can change in a standard `select` control. Certainly not reliably cross-browser, anyway.

Comment: As @RoryMcCrossan stated you have limited access for styling to `<option>` elements. You might have to use a workaround js-library that generates the `<select>` based on other elements like `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

give it a class when you create it, and you'll be able to style that class

```
$('#slctSubPurpose').append($('<option>', { 
  value: 'view more',
  text: 'View More',
  class: 'view-more'
}));    
$('#slctSubPurpose').selectric();
```